# Преобразование из socket data в numpy array

Tags: python, сокет, opencv, tcp, обработка-изображений

Пытаюсь отобразить картинку, посланную по сокетам.

Есть такой код: P.S Да-да, я знаю, что это худшее, что Вы видели, но вот он:

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data:
        print ("received data:", len(data))
        try:
            myfile = open("t.png", 'wb')
            myfile.write(data)
            img = cv2.imread('t.png')
            if not img is None:
                img = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 720))
                cv2.imshow("1", img)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)
```

Он открывает файл, записывает туда изображение, а потом opencv читает это изображение и показывает.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы opencv сразу показывало изображение?

Чтобы не записывать картинку на диск и читать, а сразу показывать.

P.S Пробовал так: `cv2.imshow("1", data)` - выдавало ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать io.BytesIO():

```
import io
img = cv2.imread(io.BytesIO(data))
```